# Multi Level Translation via TMS

Tags: 2013-sp1, translation-manager

In the BluePrint that goes

```
\ Global English 

          \ Core French (FR-FR)

                        \ Canadian French (FR-CA)
```

Assuming a new piece of content is created (at Global English) and has not yet been translated to any language.

Are the following assumptions correct?

**PUSH Translation**

I have the option to push to FR-FR and/or CA-FR. If I select both, I would expect 2 translations

1. EN to FR, then
2. FR to FR-CA

**PULL Translation**

If I do a PULL at FR-CA, I would expect 2 translations

1. EN to FR, then
2. FR to FR-CA

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

Translation Manager will not perform any "chained" translations for you automatically. So no, the assumptions are not correct.

A push job is always resulting in translations from a single source to one or more targets. A pull job is always a translation from one or more sources to a single target.

For the push job, you will get one job with EN as the source language and FR and FR-CA as the target languages.

Pull jobs work a bit different. It will look at the items included in the target. If an item originates from the English publication, it will create a job in TMS translating EN to FR-CA. If the item originates from the FR publication, it will create a job in TMS with FR to FR-CA. If items from both sources are included, you will get two jobs in TMS.

You can use event systems etc to first do the EN to FR translation and then create a new FR to FR-CA translation job, but it does increase complexity and turnaround time. I would personally investigate getting TMS to enforce the translation chain with proper use of translation memories etc instead of trying to do it in Tridion. After all, this is more of a translation workflow related task than a content management task. That said, I have no idea how easy it would be to make TMS do this.

Comment: The _translation configuration_ for an item (in FR-CA) is its parent item had it not been localized. The docs covers the [translation pull logic](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-B757B35C-B142-4B4C-8E5D-37FFCB6B90EF). Edit: removed the question.